# unable to create table errno150

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am getting error while creating table `"register"`...
there are 5 tables `astro-info`, `expectations`, `familybackground`, `personal_info`, `service-business`

I have checked data types and size of all foreign keys. They are the same. I.e. `bigint(100)` for all primaty keys in other tables. But still I am getting this error...

Please help ...

Here is my table structure ...

```
create table register(
    register_id bigint(100) primary key,
    mv_id bigint(100),
    astro_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(astro_id) 
            references `astro-info`(astro_id),
    expectation_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(expectation_id) 
            references `expectations`(expectation_id),
    familybackground_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(familybackground_id) 
            references `familybackground`(familybackground_id),
    personal_info_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(personal_info_id) 
            references `personal_info`(personal_info_id),
    service_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(service_id) 
            references `service-business`(service_id));
```

### Table structure for table `astro-info`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `astro-info` (
  ` astro_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (` astro_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

### Table structure for table `expectations`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `expectations` (
  `expectation_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (`expectation_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

### Table structure for table `familybackground`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `familybackground` (
  `familybackground_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (`familybackground_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9
```

### Table structure for table `personal_info`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personal_info` (
  `personal_info_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (`personal_info_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10
```

### Table structure for table `service-business`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service-business` (
  `service_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9
```

Comment: `150` is a foreign key mapping failure. Which of the above definitions failed? Can you also post table structures of all the `reference` tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in your table `astro-info`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `astro-info` (
  ` astro_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other irrelevant fields removed from here
  PRIMARY KEY (` astro_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Error was in 2 places:

```
  ` astro_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (` astro_id`)
```

It had a leading space with column name. And the same was not used while defining a foreign key on the column in `regster` table.

```
create table register(
    register_id bigint(100) primary key,
    mv_id bigint(100),
    astro_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(astro_id) 
            references `astro-info`(astro_id),
    expectation_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(expectation_id) 
            references `expectations`(expectation_id),
    familybackground_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(familybackground_id) 
            references `familybackground`(familybackground_id),
    personal_info_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(personal_info_id) 
            references `personal_info`(personal_info_id),
    service_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(service_id) 
            references `service-business`(service_id));
```

This definition in `register` table

```
    astro_id bigint(100),
    foreign key(astro_id) 
            references `astro-info`(astro_id),
```

does not match with following definition in `astro-info` table

```
  ` astro_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (` astro_id`)
```

**Solution**:
**Option 1**: Redifine `` ` astro_id` `` to `` `astro_id` `` in `astro-info` table.

**Option 2**: Redifine `astro_id` to have a leading space with it. As in `` ` astro_id` ``.

My suggestion is to go with *Option 1*, modify the `astro-info` table field.

Comment: thanx for your useful time...it works for me... i have modify "astro-info" table.. now its working... :D
thanx....